# Simplegui: undefined: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: python, class, codeskulptor

I'm using python and `codeskulptor`/`simplegui` to make a game, and I got this   error that said `"undefined: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"`
here when I'm defining a class.

```
import simplegui, random, time 
level = 1
balls = []
class Person():
    def __init__(self):
        self.deg = 0
        self.fall = False
        self.ball = Ball()
class Ball():
    global level
    def __init__(self):
        self.velo = 0
        self.pos = [random.randint(100, 500), 0] //error here
        self.xChange = random.randint(-5, 5)
    def move(self):
        self.velo = level
        self.pos[1] += level
        self.pos[0] += xChange
        if self.pos[0] <= 0 or self.pos[0] >= 600:
            self.xChange *= -1
        if self.pos[1] >= 500:
            self.pos[0] = random.randint(100, 500)
            self.pos[1] = 0 
class Player():
    def __init__(self):
        global balls
        self.posx = 300
        self.velo = 0
        self.gameover = False
        self.pearson = Person()
        self.ball = Ball()
        self.game = Game()
    def left(self):
        self.velo -= 0.5
        self.pearson.deg -= 0.5
    def right(self): 
        self.velo += 0.5 
        self.pearson.deg += 0.5
    def renewInfo(self):
        self.posx += self.velo
    def hit(self):
        if self.posx + 10 <= self.ball.pos[0] and self.posx - 10 >= self.ball.pos[0] and self.ball.pos[1] >= 470:
            self.game.gameover 
class Game():
    global balls
    def __init__(self):
        self.person = Person()
        self.ball = Ball()
        self.player = Player()
    def spBall(self):
        for i in range(10):
            balls.append(self.ball)
    def move(self):
        pass
    def gameover(self):
        pass
game = Game()
def draw(canvas):
    pass
def keydown(key):
    if key == 37:
        game.player.left
    if key == 39:
        game.player.right
def time_handler():
    global level
    level += 1 
timer = simplegui.create_timer(30000, time_handler)
timer.start()
frame = simplegui.create_frame('Quake Control', 800, 500)
frame.set_canvas_background('white')
frame.set_draw_handler(draw) 
frame.set_keydown_handler(keydown)
frame.start()
```

My idea is that you use arrow keys to move, and avoid balls, but you position will cause an earthquake and a person will tilt in that direction, if the person falls or you hit the ball, you lose.

Comment: Can you show the complete traceback?

Comment: The code isn't finished yet, but this is the full code.

Comment: Not the code, the traceback , the complete error.

Comment: Line 13: undefined: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be recursively creating objects for your class , Example -

```
Game() -> Player() -> Game() -> .... This goes on.
```

This is done in the lines -

For Game class -

class Game():
    global balls
    def **init**(self):
        self.person = Person()
        self.ball = Ball()
        self.player = Player()  #Notice you are creating Player object here.

For Player class -

```
class Player():
    def __init__(self):
        global balls
        self.posx = 300
        self.velo = 0
        self.gameover = False
        self.pearson = Person()
        self.ball = Ball()
        self.game = Game()      #Notice you are creating new Game() object here.
```

This is most probably what is causing the issue. You should not recursively create objects, like this, if you want the `Player()` to have a reference to the `game` pass it from the `Game()`s' `__init__()` method as an argument. Example -

```
class Player():
    def __init__(self, person, ball, game):
        global balls
        self.posx = 300
        self.velo = 0
        self.gameover = False
        self.pearson = person
        self.ball = ball
        self.game = game

class Game():
    global balls
    def __init__(self):
        self.person = Person()
        self.ball = Ball()
        self.player = Player(self.person, self.ball, self)
    def spBall(self):
        for i in range(10):
            balls.append(self.ball)
    def move(self):
        pass
    def gameover(self):
        pass
```

You are also, most probably unnecessarily creating `Ball()` object in `Person()` , most probably you want to fix that in a similar way there as well.